# Oracle SQL distinct query 3 instead of 1 line

Tags: sql, oracle

first, I've to say, that I'm very new in SQL queries but I've found a lot of help here in other questions. But now, I'm stuck.

I've following statement:

```
select  distinct part_no,
    case when cf$_package_type_db='RETAIL' then gtin_no end as retail,
    case when cf$_package_type_db='INNER' then gtin_no end as "inner",
    case when cf$_package_type_db='OUTER' then gtin_no end as outer
from part_gtin_cfv
where part_no='182400B000305'
```

This gives me below result:

[image]

What I'd like to have is just one line with the results

Comment: Does that query really execute? (Producing that result.)

Comment: Oh sorry, for the result in the screenshot, I didn't used the group by funktion! It was added when I tried to get just the one line output. I'll edit my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there will only be one for each Pat_no, try:

```
select part_no,
    max(case when cf$_package_type_db='RETAIL' then gtin_no end) as retail,
    max(case when cf$_package_type_db='INNER' then gtin_no end) as "inner",
    max(case when cf$_package_type_db='OUTER' then gtin_no end) as outer
from part_gtin_cfv
where part_no='182400B000305'
group by part_no
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I edited my original post and removed the group_by function instead it was not in the original query and it was wrong with the "_"